# what is the concept behind java iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, concept

I am doing a research on java `iterator` interface and cannot understand why it is designed like that.

Why java iterator use `hasNext` and `next` instead merge them into one method?

this a typical usage of java iterator

```
Iterator iter = //iterator from a list
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object obj = iter.next();
    // do something to obj
}
```

why not

```
Iterator iter = //iterator from a list
Object obj = null;
try {
    while(true){
        obj = iter.next();
        // do something to obj
    }
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {}
```

It is clear this approach looks ugly but what happen if `next` return null for when reach to end instead throw an exception? than code can be simplify to

```
Iterator iter = //iterator from a list
Object obj = null;
while((obj = iter.next()) != null){
    // do something to obj
}
```

this is how NSEnumerator in Objective-C works

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = // from an array
while (id obj = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    // do something to obj
}
```

---

This increase the overhead of implement custom `iterator`.

This also make java iterator not thread-safe. For example an ArrayList have one element in it. Two threads both ask for a same iterator for that list `hasNext` at same time. Than both threads will see `true` and they will invoke `next` on that iterator. Because there is only one element and iterator has been asked twice which definitely will lead to an exception or error state.

I know there are thread-safe iterator but I am not sure hot it implement but I think lots blocking are happening which make it inefficient.

I think problem is that check and update are not happen atomically and I cannot understand why java designed `iterator` interface like that.

---

**Update**

I see that null can be a value so my approach is invalid. But is any possible workaround to the problems I mentioned above?

Comment: Are you worried about the clarity of your source code, or about the performance cost of calling `hasNext()` and then `next()`?

Comment: i am doing a university course project relate to java iterator so just want to know more about it

Comment: Ok. In the real world, source code clarity is nearly always a bigger concern than minuscule performance tweaks. You'd have to execute an *awful* lot of loops before the cost of an extra method call started to become a significant contributor to execution time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proposition would make it impossible to have `null` values in collections, since it uses `null` as a "poison pill" to detect the end of the iteration.

In the very very rare cases two threads share an iterator, you just need to wrap it inside some custom class and synchronize the access to the iterator, to make the check-then-act operation atomic. This is needed anyway since, even if the iterator just had one method, the backing collection (ArrayList in your example) is not thread-safe.

Comment: oh.. i never thought null can be put into list... too used to think in Objective-C way

Comment: +1 But I would add a 2nd short sentence mentioning the reason for that. Having two states then making `next()` return null: null value or no more element. And to fix this you would have to prohibit `null` as value.

Comment: @FabianBarney Prohibiting null as a value is probably not *such* a bad idea, mind you. I still wouldn't use it to signal the end of a Java `Iterator`: it breaks the contract.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer I agree that it can make sense to restrict the usage of `null` in projects. Nevertheless in Iterables like collections `null` can really make sense and IMHO should not be generally prohibited. Think of database results stored in collections etc.

Answer (score 4):

Your first suggestion is poor design because it relies on throwing and catching an exception for a condition that is known to eventually happen. Exceptions are rather expensive, and are meant only for "exceptional" situations which should not normally occur.

Your second suggestion doesn't take into account that `Iterable`s can have null elements.

As for the thread safety bit, yes standard `Iterator`s tend not to be thread safe and a custom implementation with added overhead would be necessary. This is true for most Java structures. As [JB Nizet notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530621/697449), it's more a matter of the `Iterable` structure being thread-safe before its `Iterator` can be.

Answer (score 2):

For improved source code clarity, use (example with a collection of Strings)

```
Iterable<String> values = ... // typically a Collection (List, Set...)

for (String value : values) {
    // do something with the value
}
```

I concur with previous replies about null-bounded collections, loop control with exceptions (which is atrocious form) and thread safety.

Of your suggestions, null-bounding the collection is the least unwise, especially if you have a "no nulls" policy in your code. However it's very unidiomatic Java (edit: *and* breaks the contract of the Iterator interface), so liable to confuse future maintainers of the code (edit: and possibly cause subtle and/or unexpected bugs).